# Submit xml,saml,... to server in Web service Security

Tags: java, web-services

I am developing a web service: Book store and I am going to develop using XML or SAML security.

I prepare a form (using JSP, PHP, ASP, ASP.NET ) with some information like: book, bankaccount, amount,... And submit this form to server.  How can I do?
Please tell me step by step.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to learn a little more about how web services work. Nobody will be submitting a form to the service. They will instead have a piece of code call the web service.

Will you be developing your service in WCF in .NET 3.5 SP1? Please update your question with that detail, or say what other platform you will be using. We will then be able to tell you about the resources you will need to understand the creation of web services on that platform.

Comment: My platform is: Weblogic or Jboss, JDK1.6, JSP .
I have a form data with some field: cardnumber, bankaccount, amount,currency, ... I want to submit that parameters to an action called "PayAction.jsp". 
I want to encrypt before submit. And decrypt in "PayAction.jsp" 
by using XML or SAML,...

Comment: Maybe submitting a form to a JSP is called a web service in the Java world. It's not what we would call a web service in the .NET world. In any case, I don't know about JSP, so I'll shut up now.